# FlatList React-Native: How i can focus scroll in the specific list item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, listview, react-native, scrollview

**Context:**

I am working with "react-native" using "expo" and I have a inverted "FlatList" where it's render an "array" of months from January to December.

[image]

**Request:**

Before the list will be show to the user, the list should focus in the current month.

**Current Situation:**

I'am using "FlatList" "scrollToOffset" property to do this request,  when the list is receive the "datasource" automatically fire the "this.flatList.scrollToOffset" statement an the list animate the scroll and focus the specific item. However I have a problem, this animation is a abrupt movement that spoil the UX.

[image]

**Need:**

Can you help me to found a solution for this problem? I Need do the same but the user can't see that scroll movement, he only should see the item focused.
Any idea?

**Demonstration code:**

Flatlist

```
<FlatList
  ref={ref => (this.flatList = ref)}
  inverted
  data={foods}
  keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
  renderItem={this.renderItem}
/>
```

Function to focus item

```
handlePosition(id) {
  /* Item Size from FlatList */
  const itemSize = deviceWidth / 2 + 30;
  /* Id of the current month */
  const idCurrentItem = id;

  this.flatList.scrollToOffset({
    animated: true,
    offset: itemSize * idCurrentItem,
  });
}
```

statement where is call the handlePosition Function

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.handlePosition(this.props.months[2].id);
}
```

Comment: set `animated: false` in scrollToOffset

Comment: @ShashinBhayani Thank you, for the comment. i already used this way, however this was more abrupt, that's why i published my question.

Comment: I don't know how to avoid the animation but, you can put an ActivityIndicator (loading alert) while the animation is happening to "hide" and lock the interaction of the user until the month would be setted.

Comment: @MtgKhaJeskai Thank you for you comment. yeah, it is what i'm doing just now, was the first solution that i thought. Except that i wanted to use a of "FlatList" or "ScrollView" property that resolve this request.

Comment: Try what I answered.

Comment: I have a question in flatist. I need to scroll to the end and bottom by showing upto 15 items on click of the up and down button if I click on the Up and down button. scrollToEnd and scrollToIndex works for me. Can we have any option to show above 15 items and below 15 items and soon

Comment: @sejn https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#initialnumtorender Can it useful for you?

Answer (score 11):

Use the initialScrollIndex prop of the `FlatList` component to order the index where you want to start the FlatList.

For this, you must calculate the month before the render in the componentDidMount or componentWillMount functions where you will have to store the month(or the index) in the state. Then you would access to this state in the Flatlist component and set the initialscrollIndex to it.

Here the example of the componentWillMount function:

```
componentWillMount() {
...
  //assuming that we are on February will set index scroll to 1 being 0 January 
  //and being 3 March
  this.setState({monthToStart: 1});
}
```

Necessary statement to initialScrollIndex work successful

```
getItemLayout(data, index) {
  return (
    {
      length: yourItemHeightSize,
      offset: yourItemHeightSize * index,
      index
    }    
  );
}
```

Here the example of the FlatList component adding the new prop:

```
  <FlatList
    ref={ref => (this.flatList = ref)}
    inverted
    data={foods}
    keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
    getItemLayout={(data, index) => this.getItemLayout(data, index)}
    renderItem={this.renderItem}
    initialScrollIndex={this.state.monthToStart}
  />
```

Comment: Thank for the help, even though to work correctly this statement need the getItemLayout(). 
Too was necessary test in production because the transition was very slow in development environment.

Comment: Nice, the it worked for you? If yes, set this question as correct! Greetings